# How to not escape route parameters when generating URL?

Tags: symfony

I have an Asset entity with a field called symbol. This field can basically contain any human-readable string, including special symbols.

I'd like to generate a URL with this symbol as a parameter, but without it being escaped.

For instance I have an Asset with symbol $, but it's being generated as assets/%24

I need to be able to generate it in the Twig template without escaping these characters.

I'm using Symfony 5.

Comment: Why is this a problem to generate a URL with url encoded chars in the first place ? Can you explain what is the problem ?

Comment: I'd just prefer the URL to be more readable. A user might be confused why the URL contains /assets/%24. It's just an aesthetics issue admittedly, but still a preference if I can manage it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` is a reserved character as specified in the [RFC2393](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt) :

> 2.2. Reserved Characters
>      Many URI include components consisting of or delimited by, certain
>      special characters.  These characters are called "reserved", since
>      their usage within the URI component is limited to their reserved
>      purpose.  If the data for a URI component would conflict with the
>      reserved purpose, then the conflicting data must be escaped before
>      forming the URI.
>      reserved    = ";" | "/" | "?" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" |
>                       "$" | ","

If you don't mind not following this recommandation, you could try to `url_decode` your generated url by creating a [Twig filter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html) and use it like this :

```
{{ asset(...)|urldecode }}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know it was reserved. But the filter idea is good.